# How to add xsi:schemaLocation to serialized object

Tags: c#

How can I add the following xsi:schemaLocation to a serialized class?

```
<ern:NewReleaseMessage xmlns:ern="http://ddex.net/xml/2010/ern-main/32"
                       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                       LanguageAndScriptCode="en"
                       xsi:schemaLocation="http://ddex.net/xml/2010/ern-main/32 http://ddex.net/xml/2010/ern-main/32/ern-main.xsd"
                       MessageSchemaVersionId="2010/ern-main/32">
```

Here is what I have done so far:

```
public class NewReleaseMessage
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string LanguageAndScriptCode { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("schemaLocation", Namespace = "http://ddex.net/xml/2010/ern-main/32")] 
    public string  schemaLocation = "http://ddex.net/xml/2010/ern-main/32 http://ddex.net/xml/2010/ern-main/32/ern-main.xsd";

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string MessageSchemaVersionId { get; set; }

    [XmlElement()]
    public MessageHeader MessageHeader { get; set; }

}
```

When I deserialize the xml to the object in VS I get:

{"The method or operation is not implemented."
There is an error in XML document (5, 44) - This actually points to the line: xsi:schemaLocation="http://ddex.net/xml/2010/ern-main/32 http://ddex.net/xml/2010/ern-main/32/ern-main.xsd"

Answer (score 9):

Soultion:

```
[XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "schemaLocation", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
public string schemaLocation { get; set; }
```

Comment: Great, AttributeName is the clue (I was using ElementName with no success). And NameSpace must match to the xmlns:xsi declared. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Below is what worked for me:

Note : "XmlAttributeAttribute"

```
[XmlAttributeAttribute(AttributeName = "schemaLocation", Namespace = "http://ddex.net/xml/2010/ern-main/32")] 
public string schemaLocation = "http://ddex.net/xml/2010/ern-main/32 http://ddex.net/xml/2010/ern-main/32/ern-main.xsd";
```